# Magento 2.2.5 - Javascript intermittent loading errors when FPC cache enabled

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

I have been debugging my Magento 2 build and I have found that when cache is enabled I see intermittent JS loading errors.
If I disable the FPC cache the errors stop and the page works correctly (consistently).

No code changes are implemented, just a simple page reload.

Good page load:

[image]

Bad page load:

[image]

The errors happen approx every 3-4 page loads. Then goes away again for the next couple of page loads but then reappears.

If I disable FPC cache I do not see any errors ever (tested with approx 50 page reloads).

I have of course cleared cache, deleted pub/static/* deployed static content etc

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this was a 3rd party JS widget that was injecting jQuery 3.3.1.
Which is incompatible with core Magento jQuery.
Removing the widget resolved the issue.